# Query MongoDb to get counts from collection on array of reference id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i have total 3 collections:
1. users
2. posts
3. actions

My collections look like these:

**users:**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ee65fef5a0c032877725db"), 
    "fbId" : "EAAXZA4sZCZBKmgBAKe0JpJPrp7utWME6xbHT9yFD", 
    "name" : "Aftab", 
    "email" : "xxxe@hotmail.com", 
    "gender" : "male", 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-10-10T05:11:35.344+0000"), 
    "score" : NumberInt(90)
}
```

**actions:**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f7a0ba3a603627658afdd3"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-10-07T13:18:50.815+0000"), 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-10-07T13:18:50.815+0000"), 
    "userId" : ObjectId("57ee65fef5a0c032877725db"), 
    "postId" : ObjectId("57f4b5e98899081203883a1b"), 
    "type" : "like"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f7a0ba3a603627658afdd4"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-10-07T13:18:50.815+0000"), 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-10-07T13:18:50.815+0000"), 
    "userId" : ObjectId("57ee65fef5a0c032877725db"), 
    "postId" : ObjectId("57f4b5d58899081203883a1a"), 
    "type" : "dismiss"
}
```

**posts:**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f24593e272b5199e9351b9"), 
    "imgFileLocation" : "http://xxxx/buybye-platform/uploads/image-1475495315229", 
    "description" : "cool cool", 
    "title" : "Bad Image ", 
    "userId" : ObjectId("57f21e3d0b787d0f7ad76dd0"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f4b5d58899081203883a1a"), 
    "imgFileLocation" : "http://xxx/buybye-platform/uploads/image-1475655125125", 
    "description" : "cool & cool", 
    "title" : "Good Image", 
    "userId" : ObjectId("57f21e3d0b787d0f7ad76dd0"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

user can create posts, and other users can perform actions on those posts

posts collection has a reference of userId
and actions collection has ref of userId(who performed that action), postId(on which post) and action-type(like/dislike/dismiss)

I need to query to get all actions performed on a specific user posts

I have able to get all posts against a user, which is pretty straight-forward and is an array. now I need to get all actions performed on every single post of this posts array.

Comment: Would you care to update your question with some sample documents from the collections and your expected output from the desired aggregation? This helps with clarifying the problem as well as encouraging quality answers.

Comment: Which MongoDB version are you running?

Comment: mongodb v3.2 @Styvane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a solution that leverages the aggregation framework, you can use the `$lookup` stage that was introduced starting with MongoDB v3.2.

For example, if you want to return a result set containing the details of a post and an array of all the actions performed on that particular post, you can run the following aggregation query:

```
/*
 * QUERY #1
 */
db.posts.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'actions',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'postId',
            as: 'post_actions'
        }
    }
]);

/*
 * RESULT SET #1
 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ff4512a134e614a7178c1d"),
    "imgFileLocation" : "http://xxxx/buybye-platform/uploads/image-1475495315229",
    "description" : "cool cool",
    "title" : "Bad Image ",
    "userId" : ObjectId("57f21e3d0b787d0f7ad76dd0"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "post_actions" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("57ff4563a134e614a7178c1e"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-10-07T13:18:50.815Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-10-07T13:18:50.815Z"),
            "userId" : ObjectId("57ee65fef5a0c032877725db"),
            "postId" : ObjectId("57ff4512a134e614a7178c1d"),
            "type" : "like"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("57ff4564a134e614a7178c1f"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-10-07T13:18:50.815Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-10-07T13:18:50.815Z"),
            "userId" : ObjectId("57ee65fef5a0c032877725db"),
            "postId" : ObjectId("57ff4512a134e614a7178c1d"),
            "type" : "share"
        }
    ]
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to only retrieve the actions for a specific array of posts, you can add a `$match` stage in the aggregation pipeline:

```
const postIdsArray = [
    ObjectId("57ff4512a134e614a7178c1d"),
    ObjectId("57ee65fef5a0c032877725db")
];

/*
 * QUERY #2
 */
db.posts.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            _id: {
                $in: postIdsArray
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'actions',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'postId',
            as: 'post_actions'
        }
    }
]);
```

Furthermore, if you would want to only retrieve the total count of actions performed on a post, you can add an `$unwind` stage and then `$group` all the results:

```
/*
 * QUERY #3
 */
db.posts.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'actions',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'postId',
            as: 'post_actions'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$post_actions'
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id',
            posts: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
]);

/*
 * RESULT SET #3
 */
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57ff4512a134e614a7178c1d"), "posts" : 2 }
```

**UPDATE #1**

If you want to retrieve only the actions that are of a certain type (e.g.: like, share etc.), you can add an additional `$match` stage in your aggregation pipeline, after you `$unwind` the post_actions array retrieved in the `$lookup` stage.

For example, the first query would become:

```
/*
 * UPDATED QUERY #1
 */
db.posts.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'actions',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'postId',
            as: 'post_actions'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$post_actions'
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "post_actions.type": 'like'
        }  
    }
]);
```

The second query would become:

```
const postIdsArray = [
    ObjectId("57ff4512a134e614a7178c1d"),
    ObjectId("57ee65fef5a0c032877725db")
];

/*
 * UPDATED QUERY #2
 */
db.posts.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            _id: {
                $in: postIdsArray
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'actions',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'postId',
            as: 'post_actions'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$post_actions'
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "post_actions.type": 'like'
        }
    }
]);
```

The third query would become:

```
/*
 * UPDATED QUERY #3
 */
db.posts.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'actions',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'postId',
            as: 'post_actions'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$post_actions'
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "post_actions.type": 'like'
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id',
            posts: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Working perfectly. 
how would I get total counts of a specific action on that particular post? say "like" or "dislike"

Comment: @HaroonKhan I've updated my answer for all 3 example queries to meet your requirements. Check it out :)